# How to keep only single form open in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have VCL application in delphi. One main form and many child forms.
How to ensure only one form opened at a time. In other words, If a form is opened, it will close previous form. Or, if user try to open form that same with previous, it will do nothing.
Code to open form in my main form:

```
procedure TFMainForm.OpenForm(const classname: string);
var
  c: TPersistentClass;
  f: TForm;
begin
    c := GetClass(classname);
    if c <> nil then
    begin
      f := TForm(TControlClass(c).Create(nil));
      f.Parent := Self;
      f.Show;
    end;
end;
```

The child form is self-freed on close event.

Comment: rather dangerous hack with Form.Parent. Maybe be better to use MDI and ensure it is always maximized? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Building_a_VCL_Forms_MDI_Application_Without_Using_a_Wizard

Comment: @Arioch, I can't see anything dangerous on assigning parenthood to forms created by yourself though, but you're right, it looks like OP tries to make an MDI application in wrong way.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I try to make MDI application. But I want child form to fill only a small portion of main form. So, I set the child form borderless, and set child form's parent to main form.

Comment: @TLama QC108580 - one wrong step and you're paralyzed.

Comment: That is not MDI app. MDI in windows consists of visible main window + invisible main host window + child windows. I'd rather do MDI in the standard MDI way.

Comment: @Arioch, so then look at the code in [`that QC`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108580) and tell me if you'd do it that way for the task in this question. It's a wrong step in a wrong written code, so what's dangerous ? And anyway [`Parent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Parent) and [`ParentWindow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ParentWindow) are two similar, but still different things.

Comment: @TLama in the context of the QC Parent and ParentWindow are the same. And the requirement "if user try to open form that same with previous, it will do nothing." sounds exactly as modal windows to me and to GolezTrol. So yes, i think it was quite possible.

Comment: @Arioch'The There's a trivial fix. Don't call ShowModal on a form with Parent<>nil! And then it's just fine to set `Parent` on a form.

Comment: @David best contraception is celibacy ? Fix to ShowModal is not calling ShowModal ? I'd better say never set form's parent to anything that is form itself. But well, there are a lot of workarounds, i just pointed that current code is one step from freeze.

Comment: @Arioch'The Your *solution* cuts the nose off to spite the face.

Comment: @David, True, but i have no power to fix VCL. That solution seems better to me than to avoid having face if you have nose.

Comment: @Arioch'The Sure you can fix it. You can override ShowModal and put in a run time block. You'd do this in your common base class that all forms in your code derive from.

Comment: Oh, @David, in the context of this thread, where i warned topic starters and all potential readers, i should fix it in their copies of VCL too. That is out of reach for me, u agree? Come on, it is not worth continuing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make 'f' a variable in your mainform, instead of a local variable, you will have a reference to the currently open form. You can use that reference to close that form or to check its class.

Two notes:

- You'll have to reset the variable if you close the form without opening another.
- I wonder why you would want to do this. Isn't it more friendly to let your users decide whether they want to open multiple forms?

As an alternative, you could make the child forms modal (use ShowModal instead of Show), but that would block access to the main form when the child form is open.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above, I want the child form to fill only a small portion of main form.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the same scenario but you could have a *SubscriptionList*, where every created form is Subscribed on create and unsubscribed on destroy. In that way you can check if your window is in the list, if it doesn't exist create, if already exist move focus to the form.

We use this approach to open the same form with diferent data (an invoice for example) and track them to not open the same invoice twice.

If you are doing for example a [Dashboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashboard_%28business%29) and using a form for each piece of info you can track them all with the Subscription list instead of having a variable for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Intercept "new form is getting active" event - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen_Events

Enumerate the forms and ensure for all the other forms .Visible is false - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.CustomForms

---

*Or, if user try to open form that same with previous, it will do nothing*

What do you mean ? and how can user do it if other forms are hidden and he can no more see buttons/menus to open other forms?

Maybe all you need is TForm.ShowModal ?

Comment: This is the beginning of a world of pain. It does what the user asks, and is going to create some really cool bugs. Especially if applied to an existing codebase, which is probably what the OP is trying to do, which is probably to implement a crazy bad hack instead of fixing a bug. But since I'm heading off into mind-reading territory, I'll avoid trying to counsel the OP directly.